# What does 'texmf' stand for?

Tags: texmf

Just a (simple) short question:

Why is the LaTeX root directory called `texmf`?

Is there a meaning of the mf ending?

Comment: Thanks, though I still prefer, `textmf-dist` = "TeX Motha-F***ing Distribution"

Answer (score 60, accepted):

From [**A Directory Structure for TeX files**](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/tds/tds.pdf), [2.2 Rooting the tree](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/tds/tds.pdf#page=3):

> In this document, we shall designate the root TDS directory by `texmf`
>   (for “TEX and METAFONT”). We recommend using that name where possible,
>   but the actual name of the directory is up to the installer.

Answer (score 32):

It is short for TeX and Metafont.

Comment: +1 can you make it shorter?

Comment: I'd prefer a longer answer.

Comment: @ガベージコレクタ: How about: 'TeX & Metafont' ? `:)`

Answer (score 19):

This name was in fact used as a possible name in the very first message to the Tex directory structure list

http://tug.org/pipermail/twg-tds/1994-October/000001.html

So I think it must have been the existing name in web2c-TeX/kpathsea but I can't recall exactly.

Comment: The link is outdated and shows a "Not found" now

Comment: @evaristegd thanks for the ping, they must have  re-organised, I replaced the link with a working one.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot oh yes, It looks like I was concentrating on "why" (as in who suggested it) and forgot to answer the main part of what it stood for. That's probably why Heiko got the tick:)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oops, didn't see the other answers. Sorry.