# texmf folder: What is it and what is it good for?

Tags: texmf

In my home directory (I am a GNU/linux machine) I have a folder named 'texmf' contained two folders named 'tlpkg' and web2c'. I vaguely recall that it was created in connection with some help I once received but I have no further recollection of it.

Can anyone help me to find out what it is, what it (potentially) does and if it can be safely deleted or moved to a different location?

Comment: That is your TEXMFHOME directory, devoted to holding your personal extensions to the distribution installed on your machine.  Do those wo folders, `tlpkg` and `web2c`, contain anything?

Comment: Hi GuM. Thanks for answering. I wonder what the MF part of the folder name means? 'tlpkg' contains the file 'texlive.tlpdb' and a empty folder nmaed 'tlpobj'. 'web2c' contains a file called 'tlmgr.log'.

Comment: And so I just learned that MF stand for meta font: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/77720/what-does-texmf-stand-for?rq=1

Comment: How did you install TeX?

Comment: You would not normally have those particular directories in TEXMFHOME, certainly if you installed from upstream. And I wouldn't think you'd have them with distro packages, either. What do `kpsewhich -var TEXMFHOME` and  `kpsewhich -var TEXMFVAR` return?

Comment: /home/jb/texmf and /home/jb/.texmf-var

Comment: BTW: How do you highlight text with that greyish background??

Comment: It seems I `got it`