LaTeX distribution that can be installed on Windows 7?
I am trying to use LaTeX on my windows 7 hp laptop.
I used to use LaTeX with MIKTEX and Texmaker on this laptop for about 5 years.
Yesterday, I was running a tex file and got a missing package warning. I tried several times to install it, but at each time I got an error.
I checked the error on the internet and I learned that I should uninstall and then reinstall miktex.
I uninstalled it. However, when I tried to reinstall it, I was unable to do that and learned that MiKTeX no longer supports Windows 7.
I also tried to install TeXstudio, but then I got the following error:

Is there any alternative that I can smoothly install on Windows 7?
Thank you in advance

A bypass is copying the package (.sty, .cls) into your local folder, i.e. ypu can just use it there. // However, chances are you need also an older version of the package. So google for the package, archive, waybackmachine etc. // Once you've got it copy into the texmf tree. See e.g. https://miktex.org/kb/texmf-roots , https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/77720/what-does-texmf-stand-for . Most likely you need to initiate an update of miktex's database. // CONTACTing Miktex may be the safest approach.

You could install a historical TeX Live distro of a similar age to your OS - but that won't help with newer packages. More significantly, Windows 7 is well out-of-support by MS - this is not a sustainable position. (Win10 is almost end-of-life!)

well as you deinstalled and reinstalled miktex it is imho beyond repair. You could try an historic texlive (2023 or 2022), it contains also an editor, texworks. But your best bet is probably to use an online service like overleaf.

Hopefully he does not try to connect to the internet through this Win7 machine.

@UlrikeFischer I tried overleaf, but unfortunately, always i get compile time out for the free version §§

An alternative to MiKTex would be to try installing TexLive, which can be found at the TeX Users Group web site1.
